# C# Gzip incorrectly compress bytes array on server side

Tags: c#, ssl, server, compression, gzip

I have a problem. When I'm trying to send compressed file (byte[]) to server, and when decompress it, files do not match each other. I thought, problem is in the compress functions, but my client can compress and decompress byte array on his side. So, here's code:

Connection to server (client-side):

```
private void ConnectToServer() {
        try {
            _client = new TcpClient(_address, _port);
            _stream = new SslStream(_client.GetStream(), true,
                new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);
            try {
                _stream.AuthenticateAsClient(_address);
                _stream.Write(new byte[]{1});
            } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
                _iClient.ExceptionHandler(ex);
                _client.Close();
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            _iClient.ExceptionHandler(ex);
            _iClient.SuccessfulConnectionHandler();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Accepting client (server-side):

```
private static void SetupServer() {
        try {
            IPAddress ipAddress;
            if (!IPAddress.TryParse(_address, out ipAddress)) ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(_address)[0];
            _listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, _port);
            _listener.Start();
            WriteLine("\b\b\b - Успешно;");
            WriteLine("Ожидание подключений...");

            while (true) {
                var client = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                var sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), true);
                try {
                    sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(new X509Certificate(_certificate, _password),
                        false, SslProtocols.Tls, true);
                    WriteLine("{0} : [{1}] Успешное подключение",
                        DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        (client.Client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint)?.Address);
                    new Thread(() => ProcessClient(client, sslStream)).Start();
                } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
                    sslStream.Close();
                    client.Close();
                } 
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            WriteLine(ex.Message);
            WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        } finally {
            _listener?.Stop();
        }
    }
```

And my compression fuctions:

```
byte[] Compress1(byte[] data) {
        using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Compress)) {
            zipStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            zipStream.Close();
            return compressedStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    byte[] Decompress1(byte[] data) {
        using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(data))
        using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        using (var resultStream = new MemoryStream()) {
            zipStream.CopyTo(resultStream);
            return resultStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

So. Why does it happend?

And here is some extra information: I use ssl connection, I have problems only with big files, I can save files without compression.

Comment: you don't show where you call Compress1, pass a payload, receive a payload, and call Decompress1 - most network problems relate to encoding and/or "framing", which you aren't showing. Can we see the code that invokes those methods **in the context of** your network code?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but there are some features in sslstream. At first you can get only 1 byte (even if buffer size is much larger) and you should read remaining byte by calling Read function once more. But that's not my problem about. The maximum size of buffer you can get by calling reading function once is 16227